# How do I verify HFiles after Hbase Major Compaction?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

During HBase major compaction, the HFiles will be grouped and finally will have single HFile. How to verify the result of this compaction dynamically in programming.

Comment: Why do you need to verify it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of HFiles of a Hbase table in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212724/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-hfiles-of-a-hbase-table-in-java)

Comment: yes, to verify the result whether really the HFiles sizes has been compacted as part of validation to proceed with the other steps?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1. create table**

> create 'mytable', 'col1'

**Step 2. insert data into table**

> put 'mytable',1,'col1:name','srihari'

**Step 3. Flush the table**

> flush 'mytable'

Observe one file in below location

Location : /hbase/data/default/mytable/e6df4d1e56e3403e7f507d0e4b48c34d/col1

Repeat the step 2 and 3 one more time and observe the location we can see two files in that location.

Now execute the below command

**> major_compact 'mytable'**

Now we can see only one file in that location.

Comment: Add below property in hbase-site.xml

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction</name>
      <value>0</value>
    </property>